# Android setting cookie jsessionid

Tags: android, jsessionid

i want to ask on every api call i make i want to set cookie jsession id. How can this be done in android?
I am ussing httpget, also answer for httppost would be nice as well

thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting the headers?

Comment: You cannot set session using http requests or http client APIs , because this is a usually a server side issue to track your session. But you can use or read the jsessionid if  using apache http api , specifically i you use CookiesManager or CookieSorage

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413839/how-to-manage-sessions-with-android-application